# Is there any difference between "a gleam of hope" and "a glimmer of hope"?

Tags: phrase-usage

I'm wondering are they actually the same or there are some differences in their usage?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to the ELL. Your question is too vague, I am sure you are able to provide more context and explain your doubts. See [tour](https://ell.stackexchange.com/tour).

Comment: We more naturally say "a glimmer", not "a gleam".

Comment: Thank you! I have curious of this for long ~

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no difference in *meaning*, but there's been [a significant difference](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=gleam%20of%20hope%2Cglimmer%20of%20hope&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cgleam%20of%20hope%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cglimmer%20of%20hope%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cgleam%20of%20hope%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cglimmer%20of%20hope%3B%2Cc0) in *usage over time*...

[image]

So unless you want to sound like your great-grandparents, use ***glimmer*** rather than ***gleam*** here.

Comment: Thank you! It's really helpful.